# MODX REVO Getpage

Tags: modx

Подскажите пожалуйста

```
          [[!getPage?
                &element=`getProducts`
                &parents=[[*id]]
                &depth=`3`
                &includeTVs=`1`
                &tpl=`catalogItem`
                &getCorrectTv=`1`
                &where=`{"template":7}`
                &limit=`12`
                &tvFilters=`{"main_page_show":"1"}`
            ]]
```

В товарах есть галочка "На главной" что надо прописать тут чтобы выводились товары только с этой галочкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В modx tv параметры с типом checkbox работают очень неочевидно (зачеканный tv в админке совсем не обязательно равен "1" при выборке).
Полазай в настройках нужного tv-параметра и поиграй со значениями "Input Option Values" и "Default Value".

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/template-variables/template-variable-input-types#TemplateVariableInputTypes-CheckBox

Comment: Разобрался спасибо! а как поставить так чтобы, выводились товары сначала с этими данными, потом уже остальные?

Comment: я бы настроил tv, так, чтобы незачекнное значение представлялось как 0, а зачеканное - как 1. И после в getPage приписал бы параметр &sortbyTV = `main_page_show` и, если потребуется, добавил бы еще sortdirTV=`ASC`

[ссылка](http://modx-shopkeeper.ru/documentation/modx-revolution/snippet-getproducts.html)